# Flex SDK 3.5 - Check file magic number

Tags: apache-flex, file, magic-numbers

Related to:
[Flex SDK 3.5 - Check file mimetype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669419/flex-sdk-3-5-check-file-mimetype)

Is there a way to get a file's [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) in Flex SDK 3.5 in order to get the file type?

Comment: What's this "magic number" of which you talk? Can you post a link or similar?

Comment: There you go: It's a "constant numerical or text value used to identify a file format or protocol"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my understanding the magic number is the first couple of bytes in a file. Also, in my opinion, this is a very loose term.

So assuming that the magic number is the first bytes in a file, you could open a byte stream and check the bytes read. I think this is the only reliable way (but also very error prone and might open security problems, think about IEs' content sniffing issues). The UNIX tool `file` actually does that and still, it is called a file type guesser.

The actual number depend on the file format you are trying to use. If you are lucky it's documented. If not, it might get painful.